# Problema de Codificação Entre Cliente JavaScript e Servidor Python

Tags: javascript, python, socket, codificação-de-caracteres, websocket

Tenho um servidor socket em Python, segue o código:

```
from socket import *

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 6060

try:
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((host, port))
    server.listen(5)
    print('Servidor Python escutando...')

    client = server.accept()

    while True:
        data = client.recv(2048)
        if not len(data):
            break

        print(data)
        print(data.decode())       

    server.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

E tenho o cliente socket em JavaScript, segue o código:

```
socket = new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:6060')

socket.onopen = function(event)
{
    let data = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode('Cliente JavaScript conectado')
    socket.send(data)
}
```

Eu executo o servidor Python pela linha de comando, depois acesso o arquivo .html (com o código do cliente socket entre tags script) no navegador, mas logo depois que eu abro a página no navegador, eu recebo o seguinte erro no terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "server.py", line 20, in <module>
        print(data.decode())
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 8: invalid start byte
```

O Cliente JavaScript se conecta, mas no servidor Python, na hora de decodificar a mensagem que está em bytes, ocorre esse erro.

Já quando crio um cliente socket em Python, roda tudo normalmente e não é acusado nenhum erro na decodificação da mensagem.

No console do navegador, a mensagem javascript que codifico com o método encode do objeto TextEncoder é apresentada dessa forma:

```
Uint8Array(28) [67, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 101, 32, 74, 97, 118, 97, 83, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 32, 99, 111, 110, 101, 99, 116, 97, 100, 111]
```

Já no python, ela é recebida dessa forma pela função ***print(data)***:

```
b'\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03\xc8.>\xbd\x9e\xb4.\x176%%&\xe1\xdf\x8a\xb0T\xc3s\xbb\x06\x1e\xec*\xf7\xdb\r\xdbE\xd4V; Nl\xc6P\xb9\x9dsa\xe51D\xc0r4V\xed\xe3\x0b\x87K5\x1e\x99b\x80\x99\xc8\xf04OG\xed\x00 \xda\xda\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xc0+\xc0/\xc0,\xc00\xcc\xa9\xcc\xa8\xc0\x13\xc0\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x93\xaa\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\n\x00\n\x00\x08\xaa\xaa\x00\x1d\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x12\x00\x10\x04\x03\x08\x04\x04\x01\x05\x03\x08\x05\x05\x01\x08\x06\x06\x01\x00\x12\x00\x00\x003\x00+\x00)\xaa\xaa\x00\x01\x00\x00\x1d\x00 \x82\xbfo\xe73\x88**U\xbb\xba a\xe1\xdd%\x069\xda\xde\xe0\x95\x9f\xcd\x0eQ\xf2\x1fb\xa7-P\x00-\x00\x02\x01\x01\x00+\x00\x0b\nzz\x03\x04\x03\x03\x03\x02\x03\x01\x00\x1b\x00\x03\x02\x00\x02\xda\xda\x00\x01\x00\x00\x15\x00\xf7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Como faço para codificar um texto para bytes em JavaScript de uma forma que eu consiga decodificá-lo no python sem esse problema?

Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: O problema está na forma como o Socket está escrito na linguagem Javascript. É necessário sempre rever o código como máxima atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Estás a confundir conceitos. A biblioteca [**`socket`** [Python-docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) é diferente de [**`websockets`**](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html).

No teu caso, queres implementar um `websocket` para comunicar entre o servidor Python e o browser (através do módulo `WebSocket` do JavaScript).

Atenção que tal como o `https` só funciona com um certificado SSL válido, o protocolo `wss` também só pode ser usado com um certificado SSL válido. Caso não tenhas um certificado, deves alterar o código JavaScript para:

```
socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6060')
```

A implementação de um servidor websocket básico a partir da [**`documentação`**](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html).

```
import asyncio
import websockets #pip install websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    data = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"RECEIVED >> {data.decode('utf8')}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "127.0.0.1", 6060)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

#RECEIVED >> Cliente JavaScript conectado
```

Os dados são descodificados corretamente.